# URL rewriting - Remove a subfolder from the url

Tags: wordpress, laravel, url-rewriting

I don't often ask questions on SOF because I usually find the answers just searching on SOF. This time it's a tough one for me! I don't have a lot of experience with htaccess. In fact I don't have much experience, 6 months out of school now!

I am working on a personal project using Wordpress 4.9.8 and  Laravel 5.7.
Wordpress will is used as the entry point and the articles part, Laravel will be used for the app part to display large amount of info from database.

I am developing locally with Xampp and MySql Workbench.

I am using a virtual host to simulate the domain name.

The project is structured like so in the root folder:

- Wordpress folders and files
- htaccess
- Laravel folder

  - all folders and files from Laravel
  - public

    - htaccess

The project URL is like so:

- dev.domain.com/ -->Wordpress part
- dev.domain.com/plants/public --> Laravel part

I need to hide the **"public"** folder of the URL only and still access that directory.
So far I was able to redirect directly skipping the root folder of Laravel using htaccess.

- dev.domain.com/plants **to** dev.domain.com/plants/public

I can't seem to put the finger on it after trying everything that I found that makes sense and not sure exactly where to put it. At the root of the project or in the public directory for this part?

Here is what I have in the root of the project:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/plantes [NC]
   RewriteRule . plantes/public [L]
</IfModule>
```

What I have in the public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    -- Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    -- Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    -- Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Thanks for any help or tips!

Answer (score 0):

After trying some solution found on SOF and elsewhere without any success, I turned around to review the way I structured the project to see if there is other simpler way to do this without htaccess.

Here is the new structure:

- Wordpress folders and files
- htaccess (no particular rules here so far except the ones form WP)
- MyApp

  - Laravel folder (containing all folders and files from Laravel except the public folder)

    - The content of the public folder

For this to work we need to change some references in the index.php that was in the public folder to reflect the new structure.

Index.php:

- require **DIR** . '/Laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
- $app = require_once **DIR** . '/Laravel/bootstrap/app.php';

That it's... It works!

www.domain.com/myapp/what-ever...

No URL with the public folder in the way.

Now I will need to work to change the name of "MyApp" so it can reflect multi languages using htaccess.

During my search I found this very helpfull: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybJYyU5FPv4